# storing input into malloc array (1d and 2d) and printing

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am tryin to take input from the user and store it into an array and print it out: i have 2 functions:

```
 /* Read a vector with n elements: allocate space, read elements,
    return pointer */
double *read_vector(int n){
    double *vec = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       vec[i] = n;

    return vec;
}
```

and the print function is:

```
void print_vector(int n, double *vec){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       printf("%d\n", vec[i]);
    }
}
```

the main function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *read_vector(int n);
void print_vector(int n, double *vec);
void free_vector(double *vec);

int main(){
    int n;
    double *vector;
    /* Vector */
    printf("Vector\n");
    printf("Enter number of entries: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter %d reals: ", n);
    vector = read_vector(n);
    printf("Your Vector\n");
    print_vector(n,vector);
    free_vector(vector);
}
```

when i run this, it does not let me enter any numbers, it just skips it and prints out 0's. How do i fix this?

Comment: "it does not let me enter any numbers"  So you do not get a chance to enter in `n` between `printf("Enter number of entries: ");` and `printf("Enter %d reals: ", n);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. You're almost certainly either not compiling with warnings, or ignoring the warnings. All warnings mean something, and to a beginner they all matter. With gcc use the -Wall option, or even -pedantic.

As halfelf pointed out, you need a scanf in your read loop but it needs to be a pointer (&vec[i]). Always return something at the end of main. Also check the return value of malloc, it could fail and return a null pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double *read_vector(int n)
{
    double *vec = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter number %i of %i: ", i + 1, n);
        scanf("%lf", &vec[i]);
    }
    return vec;
}

void print_vector(int n, double *vec)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", vec[i]);
    }
}

void free_vector(double *vec)
{
    free(vec);
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    double *vector;

    printf("Vector\n");
    printf("Enter number of entries: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    vector = read_vector(n);
    printf("Your Vector\n");
    print_vector(n, vector);
    free_vector(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey CaptainMurphy, thanks very much. I just have a follow up to print id's:
how do i put out the numbers like this: say i enter: 1.5 , it will display like: 
  1.50e+00

Comment: %e or %g will work. Take a look at the printf format specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

In the `read_vector(int n)` function's for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
   vec[i] = n;       // this should be scanf("%lf",vec+i) to read input from stdin
```

and notice your `{` and `}` there. If there's only one line in the loop, `{` and `}` is not necessary, OR you have to use a pair of them. The `return` clause must be out of the loop.

Btw, add `return 0` at the end of your main function.

Comment: I just edited the changes you said in, but it gave an segmentation fault.

Comment: the read_vector function is now :
double *read_vector(int n){
    double *vec = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       scanf("%lf",vec[i])
       return vec;
}

Answer (score 0):

simple..you forgot to write scanf..!

```
double *read_vector(int n)
{

    double *vec = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       scanf("%d",&vec[i]);

    return vec;
}
```